# Web sracping with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How to get the text in below Html code? There is no tag for that text.
BOĞAZİÇİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (İSTANBUL)( Devlet)

```
results=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"reading"})
results=soup.find_all("table",attrs={"class":"table"})
results=soup.find("tbody")
results=soup.find_all("tr")
results=soup.find_all("td",attrs={"style":"text-align: center; width: 490px;"},limit=10)
for result in results:
    result=result.span
    result=result.strong
    print(result)
```

I got the same result whether I used the "strong" tag or not. What should I do? I also share the website link on below.

https://www.basarisiralamalari.com/elektrik-elektronik-muhendisligi-taban-puanlari-2020-ve-basari-siralamalari-osym/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get text from first column, you can do this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.basarisiralamalari.com/elektrik-elektronik-muhendisligi-taban-puanlari-2020-ve-basari-siralamalari-osym/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'), 'html.parser')

for span in soup.select('tr > td:nth-child(1)'):
    print(span.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Üniversite
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KONYA GIDA VE TARIM ÜNİVERSİTESİ Mühendislik ve Mimarlık Fakültesi(Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KONYA GIDA VE TARIM ÜNİVERSİTESİ Mühendislik ve Mimarlık Fakültesi(Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KONYA GIDA VE TARIM ÜNİVERSİTESİ Mühendislik ve Mimarlık Fakültesi(Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KTO KARATAY ÜNİVERSİTESİ Mühendislik Fakültesi (KONYA)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KTO KARATAY ÜNİVERSİTESİ Mühendislik Fakültesi (KONYA)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KTO KARATAY ÜNİVERSİTESİ Mühendislik Fakültesi (KONYA)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KOÇ ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (İSTANBUL)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOĞAZİÇİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (İSTANBUL)( Devlet)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
İHSAN DOĞRAMACI BİLKENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (ANKARA)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORTA DOĞU TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (ANKARA)( Devlet)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOBB EKONOMİ VE TEKNOLOJİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (ANKARA)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ÖZYEĞİN ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (İSTANBUL)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
İHSAN DOĞRAMACI BİLKENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (ANKARA)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KOÇ ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (İSTANBUL)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOBB EKONOMİ VE TEKNOLOJİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ   Mühendislik Fakültesi (ANKARA)( Vakıf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```